# Option in Android to control Data Usage

Tags: android

I want to make an application which will list out all installed application in the phone. Now I want the option for the user to enable / disable the data usage for a particular app(background internet usage). How can I do that.

Please let me know some link to achieve the target.

I have already seen that under settings-> datausage -> Onclick of each app you see the option to disable the background data usage.(Sony phone)

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Implement a Service which will be run all the time in background, now implement the app package change receiver in it and when ever you receive this, get all the install apps, using App Manager, and verify with your blocked list. If match kill that process.

Comment: I don't see any background data usage control here.

Comment: The flow from other app will be, open app-> if net available-> update the status. In background, If service get any notification, it will be  reflected on the app. If I want to stop the application from using                                                         1) Internet only in background then      2) All time restricted       for selected apps provided net is available all time.

Comment: Above service will only run for the app restriction, If you want to fetch the block app lists from the server, fetch them and save them into the SQlite DB, Your app restrict service will always check your DB to get the blocked app lists.